# Text in "Next privilege" (Access moderator tools) popup in Summary page of profile doesn't make sense

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, privileges, wording, review-history

I was looking at [my profile summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/846219/random-person) and noticed this:

[image: next privilege in user profile]

If I click on my *Next privilege* tracker (i.e., for *Access moderator tools*), a pop-up containing this text is shown:

> Access reports, delete questions, review reviews

What is "review reviews"? It sounds so vague to me. Can you please improve the wording?

Answer (score 8):

"review reviews" is also present in the [/help/privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page for the 10k tools. What that wording is trying to refer to is that users with 10k reputation can view the review history by all users in any review queue by navigating to that queue's "History" page. Without this privilege, users can only view their own review history. This enables users with this privilege to effectively review others' review queue actions.

Here's how that looks on Meta SE's Close Vote queue for the moment:

[image: "image of Close Vote queues full review history]

Your confusion is absolutely not without merit, though, as the mention of this tidbit is only present as one bullet point in the [access to moderator tools help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> You now have access to various lists and statistical reports, giving you a broad overview of activity on the site:
>
> ...
>
> - The full history of reviews by *all* users in any [review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)

It's a small, but very useful, privilege to have.

Comment: I absolutely agree that it's a useful privilege. A better wording will help me to consider 10k as my target ;)

Comment: Understandable :) I'm really not sure what a good replacement would be though. "View full review history" maybe?

Answer (score 3):

This is a seldomly mentioned privilege, it has its own tag [review-history](/questions/tagged/review-history) and the [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/review-history/info) does a good job of describing the feature. After I gained 10k it took me a few days to realize what the *"review reviews"* mentioned in the Help Center actually meant.

The most obvious way to find it are the links in the general `/review` page, but the links are surprisingly easy to miss until you notice them the first time.

[image: review page]

Also inside each review queue (in the example `/review/close`) a new tab becomes available titled *History*:

[image: inside a specfic review queue]